# Database login failed

Tags: c#, sql, authentication

I am getting an error when i try to copy some data from a database to a .txt file.

My line reads:

```
string connString;
connString = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Ochhi che guardano;Integrated Security=SSPI";
```

But i get this error: "Cannot open database requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user... etc.

Comment: put username and password in connection string.

Comment: Clear enough. The account that the application is running under doesn't have login permissions on the database you are trying to connect to. Fix that.

Comment: I know that, but i don't know how to give these permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using integrated security, which means that the user who is running your program needs to have the relevant access permissions on the database. If you are running the program interactively (e.g., it is not a service), then YOU need the access permissions, that is, the account that you used to log into Windows needs to be given the permissions on the database. If you do not control the database, then speak to the person who does - normally the database administrator (DBA).

You also need to consider who will be using your program in future, e.g., when it goes live. If it will not be you, then whoever it is will need to be given the database permissions, assuming you continue to use integrated security; if your program runs as a service, then the account the service uses will need to be given the database permissions.